# Fast circuit for popcount comparison

Tags: bit-manipulation, verilog, system-verilog, hamming-distance, digital

I'm designing a circuit that needs to check if the popcount (number of bit sets to 1) of two 16-bit vectors are equal. So what I need is to perform the operation

```
logic[15:0] A,B;

if (popcount(A) == popcount(B)) begin
...
end
```

(here popcount is assumed to be an already defined function)

The trivial solution is indeed to compute the actual values and compare them, but I was wondering if there is another way requiring less levels of logic to  complete the operation. I tried to think about a way to exploit their parity, but without much success...

Comment: Just write the logic in a human-readable way and let the synthesizer deal with optimizing it.

Comment: there are some population count algorithms around designed to reduce logic levels. Here is an example: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.534.7271&rep=rep1&type=pdf. There are definitely more. Search for htem.